# Add reference visual studio 2013 specific version property set default to false

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Is it possible to set the default `value` specific version `property` to `false`, for adding a `reference` in Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea what your question means. You need to expand it a bit. Which property of what are you talking about?

Comment: That is the default, I believe.

Comment: Hallo, 
@Damien_The_Unbeliever I tested it at home with Visual Studio 2012 there false is the default. At work with Visual Studio 2013 there the default is true. I don't now where is the diffrence. I like to know if there an option where I can change the default for it.

Comment: Hallo, @simonatrcl the Problem is when i go in Visual Studio to Project Explorer->And Click Add Reference
then I select the reference to the .net dll

Comment: After I added the reference I click on the reference in Projecttree to open the properties tab of the Reference and there is one property called "specific version" and its set to true

So I like thats set this option is false if i add a reference. I like to now where I can change the default value for this propperty.